# Cloud Tasks cannot invoke Cloud Function using deterministic URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

Cloud Function gen2 now [supports](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#url) two types of HTTP URLS:

- Deterministic: `https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME`
- Non-Deterministic: `https://FUNCTION_NAME-RANDOM_HASH-REGION.a.run.app`

With non-deterministic URLs, you can simply create a Cloud Task that authenticates with the function, using the following [OIDC configuration](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/OidcToken):

```
task: {
  httpRequest: {
    url: "https://FUNCTION_NAME-RANDOM_HASH-REGION.a.run.app/something",
    httpMethod: "POST",
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: "my-function-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    },
    ...
}
```

However, if you switch the `url` to the deterministic variant, the resulting Cloud Task will no longer be able to invoke the Cloud Function and will fail with `unaUTHENTICATED(16): HTTP status code 401`.

Answer (score 2):

`oidcToken` also has an `audience` field:

> `audience`
>
> string
>
> Audience to be used when generating OIDC token. If not specified, the URI specified in target will be used.

While the `@google-cloud/tasks` NodeJS client (or Google API) can correctly derive the `audience` for non-deterministic URLs, this does not seem to be the case for deterministic ones.

You have to explicitly define the audience.

```
task: {
  httpRequest: {
    url: "https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME/something",
    httpMethod: "POST",
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: "my-function-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      audience: "https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME"
    },
    ...
}
```

Also, please note that if your URL has additional sub-paths (e.g. `/something` above), it has to be removed for `audience`.

Comment: Nice catch on the audience.